# Do I need type assert in arms of if x == nothing

Tags: julia

```
@noinline g(x::Int) = x > 2 ? 1 : nothing
function test(x::Int)
    a = g(x)
    if a == nothing
        f(a)
        # Do I need f(a::Void)
    else
        f(a)
        # Do I need f(a::Int)
    end
end

@noinline f(x) = 1
@noinline f(x::Int) = 2
@noinline f(x::Void) = 3
```

Am I right to say julia doesn't know the type of `x` when calling `f`. SO it would do a dynamic dispatch? (Of course both types of dispatch gives the correct result)

`(Main.f)(a::Union{Int64, Void})::Int64`

For performance reason, do I need to annotate my code in the arms so that Julia can do static dispatch instead of dynamic dispatch when calling `f`?

```
@code_warntype test(3)

Variables:
  #self#::#test
  x::Int64
  a::Union{Int64, Void}
  #temp#@_4::Core.MethodInstance
  #temp#@_5::Bool
  #temp#@_6::Core.MethodInstance
  #temp#@_7::Int64
  #temp#@_8::Core.MethodInstance
  #temp#@_9::Int64

Body:
  begin 
      a::Union{Int64, Void} = $(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for g(::Int64), :(Main.g), :(x))) # line 4:
      unless (a::Union{Int64, Void} isa Int64)::Bool goto 6
      #temp#@_4::Core.MethodInstance = MethodInstance for ==(::Int64, ::Void)
      goto 15
      6: 
      unless (a::Union{Int64, Void} isa Void)::Bool goto 10
      #temp#@_4::Core.MethodInstance = MethodInstance for ==(::Void, ::Void)
      goto 15
      10: 
      goto 12
      12: 
      #temp#@_5::Bool = (a::Union{Int64, Void} == Main.nothing)::Bool
      goto 17
      15: 
      #temp#@_5::Bool = $(Expr(:invoke, :(#temp#@_4), :(Main.==), :(a), :(Main.nothing)))
      17: 
      unless #temp#@_5::Bool goto 36 # line 5:
      unless (a::Union{Int64, Void} isa Int64)::Bool goto 23
      #temp#@_6::Core.MethodInstance = MethodInstance for f(::Int64)
      goto 32
      23: 
      unless (a::Union{Int64, Void} isa Void)::Bool goto 27
      #temp#@_6::Core.MethodInstance = MethodInstance for f(::Void)
      goto 32
      27: 
      goto 29
      29: 
      #temp#@_7::Int64 = (Main.f)(a::Union{Int64, Void})::Int64
      goto 34
      32: 
      #temp#@_7::Int64 = $(Expr(:invoke, :(#temp#@_6), :(Main.f), :(a)))
      34: 
      return #temp#@_7::Int64
      36:  # line 7:
      unless (a::Union{Int64, Void} isa Int64)::Bool goto 41
      #temp#@_8::Core.MethodInstance = MethodInstance for f(::Int64)
      goto 50
      41: 
      unless (a::Union{Int64, Void} isa Void)::Bool goto 45
      #temp#@_8::Core.MethodInstance = MethodInstance for f(::Void)
      goto 50
      45: 
      goto 47
      47: 
      #temp#@_9::Int64 = (Main.f)(a::Union{Int64, Void})::Int64
      goto 52
      50: 
      #temp#@_9::Int64 = $(Expr(:invoke, :(#temp#@_8), :(Main.f), :(a)))
      52: 
      return #temp#@_9::Int64
  end::Int64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth noting that Julia *isn't* doing dynamic dispatch in the example as you've written it.  Julia 0.6 actually does the optimization you're trying to achieve here.  That's what's happening in lines like:

```
  unless (a::Union{Int64, Void} isa Int64)::Bool goto 23
  #temp#@_6::Core.MethodInstance = MethodInstance for f(::Int64)
  goto 32
  23: 
  unless (a::Union{Int64, Void} isa Void)::Bool goto 27
  #temp#@_6::Core.MethodInstance = MethodInstance for f(::Void)
  goto 32
```

It's "splitting" the union and explicitly adding branches to get the exact method instance.

The way you've written it, though, Julia has a missing optimization for `==`.  In this case `x == nothing` simply calls `x === nothing`, but inference doesn't take advantage of that fact right now.  So you end up with *lots* of nested branches.  Change `==` to the stricter `===` and you get the optimization you're looking for:

```
julia> function test(x::Int)
           a = g(x)
           if a === nothing
               # … same as above

julia> @code_warntype test(2)
Variables:
  #self#::#test
  x::Int64
  a::Union{Int64, Void}

Body:
  begin
      a::Union{Int64, Void} = $(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for g(::Int64), :(Main.g), :(x))) # line 3:
      unless (a::Union{Int64, Void} === Main.nothing)::Bool goto 6 # line 4:
      return 3
      6:  # line 7:
      return 2
  end::Int64
```

This is actually much more efficient than using type assertions.

Interestingly, the `f` methods are *so* simple that Julia still inlines them despite the `@noinline` annotations.  Make them any more complicated than a single literal value and it won't inline.